# How to I get `child_process.execFile` to use the already running application

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I'm building an `Electron` app to launch some other application (for example `Photoshop`) with `child_process.execFile` and if `Photoshop` is already running when I call `child_process.execFile`, another instance of `Photoshop` is launched. How do I prevent this from happening? I checked the documentation and I couldn't find any options that force this.

I'm expecting the `Photoshop` to open the second file in a second `Photoshop` window.

Also, I need to do this is a platform independent way as this `Electron` application is being made available on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Use [app.makeSingleInstance(callback)](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.36.10/docs/api/app.md#appmakesingleinstancecallback) to make your application single instance. That way there's no need to implement any workarounds.

Comment: I'm trying to make the application I'm launching from my `Electron` app to be a single instance, not the application I'm building.